# Swift iOS: pass Image to other VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to pass and re-pass an image between two ViewControllers. My approach so far:

```
if segue.identifier == "chooseCat"
    {
        let IVC: AddProductVC = segue.destinationViewController as! AddProductVC


        IVC.pname2 = pname
        IVC.pnick2 = pnick
        IVC.pno2 = pno
        IVC.podate2 = podate
        IVC.pmanu2 = pmanu

        IVC.cidnew2 = cidnew
      //  IVC.imageImage.image = imageImage3.image


    }
```

Edit: To prevent irritations. pname...pnick and the others are variables as strings that are working correctly. The big point is `imageImage3.image`.

Unfortunately it does not work as the app crashes. Actually I don't really want to pass the image directly to a UIImage; I'd rather have it as data if that's somehow possible. The tricky part is that it is a TableViewController and not a normal ViewController where I could hide `imageImage3.image`.

Comment: What is pName2, pNo2 etc etc?

Comment: other var (string) that are working so far. thxfor asking. just edited question

Comment: It's no harder to add properties to a `UITableViewController` subclass than it is to a `UIViewController` subclass if that's what you mean by "I'd rather have it as data".

Comment: well i never dealt with that. can you help me on that with a little example?

Comment: You can just pass it into a UIImage variable and then check if it's present on IVC and assign it there if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you set the image property of an imageImage, which may be an outlet of type UIImageView that does not exist yet! If it is so, then create an UIImage property of your AddProductVC viewcontroller and pass the image to it. And then, when your views are all properly loaded, set up your imageView.

**Example** : Suggested by @iRealMe

To pass image, you can do like

```
    IVC.image = imageImage3.image
```

and now in your `AddProductVC`

```
    var image: UIImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
```